# Sitefinity site in local machine with out any changes, but image is not loading

Tags: content-management-system, development-environment, sitefinity

Hosted sitefinity site in local machine with existing code and db backup. But the image is not loading in the site front end and also in the admin side. Need some help on this. The existing live site is having images but trying to replicate it in local, it is not showing any images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot it looks the images are stored in the File System.

Make sure you manually copy all files from App_Data / Storage folder.